# AngularJS detect if dropdown has changed by button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS so I need your help. 
How do I check by button click if user has selected from dropdown? I have two dropdowns and I need to check if user has selected from either of the two dropdowns. If he doesn't select and clicks on Submit button, a modal will prompt.

This is what I've tried so far:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="supplier" name="supplier" class="form-control"
  ng-model="searchFormData.supplier" ng-change="changeMeChange()"
  ng-options="supplier.company as supplier.company for supplier in suppliersObj">
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.changeMeChange = function() {
    alert('You changed me!');
};
```

But this only notifies if the dropdown is changed but not in the button click.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Use `ng-click` over `button` element and check the value of the `model`

Comment: @RayonDabre hi thanks can you provide a sample code or tutorial?

Comment: Your question seems incomplete to me.. Provide a `fiddle` or demo to work with.. Where is `select` input and button ?

Comment: Wondering any of the answers helped..!

Answer (score 0):

I would set two scope variables for both dropdowns using ng-model to store the selected value, then in the function for the ng-click of the button you can check both variables to see what value do they have.

Comment: Can you share some sample snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `ng-model` is pointing to `searchFormData.supplier`, if the user selects an option, it'll have the selected value. So you can do the following in buttons click:

```js
$scope.submitClick = function() {
  if (!$scope.searchFormData.supplier){
    alert('You did not select supplier!');
    return false
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-click="myMethod()"` with **button** you will enter to the method called if you click, and to see if it works correctly, use `console.log("hello world")` and see the console of your web browser to see if it print the message ;P

Example code:

Ok I made this example code, see how it works **(datos is my controller)**

-HTML

```
<select id="supplier" name="supplier" class="form-control"
  ng-model="test.supplier" ng-change="changeMeChange()"
  ng-options="item as item.name for item in datos.testS track by item.id">
</select>
<button ng-click="datos.testSlack(test.supplier)">Check</button>
```

-Controller

```
$scope.testSlack = function(data){
    console.log("go");
    console.log(data.name);
  }
```

We get data from ng-model of select, and we put it as params on the method of the buton.

With data you will have the value of the select choose, **just if is null is because the user dont select anything**, I hope i'll help you ;P

Comment: Hi if I understand correctly, I will create a method for my button and then how can I check if dropdown has changed?

Comment: You save the return in ng-model, so you just need to see your $scope.ngModel that you put in, and compare the values or see if it's null, i dont know if you are understanding me

Answer (score 0):

Try this to trigger the button click on select box

```
$scope.changeMeChange = function() {
        alert('You changed me!');
    };

     <select ng-click='changeMeChange()'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you are looking to detect does user has changed the dropdown value of field or not. So for that you could use angular `form` validation, where you can check that field has been `$dirty`/`$pristine` or not. Based on that you could show `modal` **OR** can call particular function.

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="mySubmit()">
  <select id="supplier" name="supplier" class="form-control"
     ng-model="searchFormData.supplier" ng-change="changeMeChange(searchFormData.supplier, supplier)"
     ng-options="supplier.company as supplier.company for supplier in suppliersObj">
  </select>
  ...other fields...
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changeMeChange = function(field, supplier) {
    //field.$pristine OR !field.$dirty will tell you does field has changed or not
    if(!supplier && field.$pristine){
       //open modal from here.
    }
    else{
        alert('You changed me!');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes" 
   ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>


$scope.changeMeChange = function() {
  alert('You changed me!');
};
```

you can try this way once model change the will invoke alert

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind click event to button for check the drop-down model values.

Below is sample code:

HTML code for button:

```
<button data-ng-click="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

Angular Code: Function for click event to check drop-down values.

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    //Check model values of dropdown over here, based upon the result you can show prompt. 
    // You can access model value by scope variables.
};
```

Hope above sample code helps to you to resolve your problem.

Comment: how does it relates to question?

Comment: @PankajParkar - he needs to check drop-down values on submit button using angular JS, so he can add click event to the button and check it out drop-down values in that if it's not fill then show prompt by that. I haven't add full code, I just added sample code only.

Comment: @PankajParkar, He mentioned below line. " How do I check by button click if user has selected from dropdown?" so I guess he needs to check on button click that user changed dropdown OR not!

Comment: honestly speaking question is very unclear.. let see OP's next edit. :p

Comment: Yeah @PankajParkar, Firstly he asked for above things as I mentioned in my comments. That's the reason I have given sample code only, not full code.